# Anypoint Studio-Mule ESB create custom Socket Listener

Tags: java, sockets, mule, esb, mule-flow

i need to implement a simple mule esb flow with Anypoint Studio.

What i need is to open-up a socket listener on the starting of the flow, and sending to a second Java component the messages which came to the listener...

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tcp:connector or ssl:connector, for example:

```
<!-- Connector --> 
<tcp:connector name="tcpConnector" validateConnections="true" receiveBufferSize="102400" clientSoTimeout="10000" receiveBacklog="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="TCP connector"> 
    <tcp:eof-protocol payloadOnly="true" rethrowExceptionOnRead="true"/> 
</tcp:connector>

<!-- Endpoints -->    
<tcp:endpoint name="tcpEndpoint" host="${tcp.endpoint.host}" port="${tcp.endpoint.port}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="TCP"/>

<flow name="tcpFlow" doc:name="tcpFlow">
   <inbound-endpoint ref="tcpEndpoint" doc:name="Generic"/>
   <logger level="INFO" doc:name="log" message="Receive payload #[payload]" />
   <component class="...Component" doc:name="" doc:description=""/>
</flow>
```